# Sum with group in report footer

Tags: ms-access, report

I have an MS Access 2003 report which shows all transactions not grouped by currency.  At the end of the report (in the report footer section), I want to display the total of all the transactions in the report, but by the currency which they are in.  In SQL, I would use this query:

```
SELECT [Currency], SUM([Amount])
FROM myTable
GROUP BY [Currency]
```

and I would show one label for each record in the returned data.  Is there a way to accomplish this in MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, create another report showing the result of the above query (dont forget about the alias for sum field) and include it in your report footer as subreport (see the Design menu, same where you take textboxes, labels, etc).